# Is there a parametric regression model that has a convex shape and is bounded between [0,1]?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, nonparametric

I am trying to model probability $p$ as a non linear function of predictor $x$. That is,

$p=f(x)$

I would like $f$ to be a convex function of $x$ (because that's what the underlying theory would suggest to be appropriate for the relationship I am trying to model). And just like in GLM, it would be good if we can somehow bound $f(x)$ to be between $[0,1]$, so when i do confidence interval I won't get out of bound probability. Maybe we can use some link function here but I couldn't work out how to keep the convex shape with a link function.

Is there a parametric $f$ that I can use?

Comment: Claim is not true. You need a sigmoid like function https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378369/when-is-logit-function-preferred-over-sigmoid/378376#378376

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc assuming you are referring to the claim 'theory suggests...' -- i might have misled you. I don't mean statistical theory, but the domain theory regarding the relationship I am trying to model. I have edited the question.

Comment: Otherwise put, what can you tell us about $x$?

Comment: I can only give you a made up scenario (so this is not related to what I am really modelling at all). Suppose $p$ is the probability of contracting covid 19 in the next month, and $x$ is the number of people with covid19 in your neighbourhood. I would think that as $x$ increases $p$ should increase with no sign of plateauing, therefore no  S shape curve.

Comment: This will give you a concave function, not a convex one with an asymtote at positive infinity. It is achievable if x is bounded from the left.

Comment: can you elaborate why this will give me a concave function?

Comment: Ever increasing convex function will not stop at 1, which is the maximum probability. You need to plateau at positive infinity. This is not against what you are trying to model, the more people you have the more likely to catch the disease eventually becoming absolutely certain at infinity.

Comment: mmm... i think i am now convinced that $f$ doesn't need to be convex.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear to me.

For logistic regression, the objective function (loss respect to coefficients) is convex, and the model is able to produce a number bounded from 0 to 1.

Which means

$$p_i = \text{Logit}^{-1}(f(x_i)) = \text{Logit}^{-1}(\beta^T x_i)$$

is bounded in 0,1

but the objective function

$$\sum_i -y_i\log(p_i) - (1 - y_i)\log(1 - p_i)$$

is convex.

---

To summarize the link function is not convex, but the objective function that we are trying to optimizing is convex.

Comment: thanks for responding, I am essentially doing a curve fitting exercise, and I would like the shape of the curve `f(x)` (not the objective function) to be convex. For example, `f(x)=exp(x)` would do, except that is not bounded to `[0,1]`.